# Волк зарезал овцу

Tags: глаголы, словосочетания

Почему говорят "волк зарезал овцу"? Причем здесь глагол "резать"? У волка есть зубы, но зубы не "режущий инструмент". По-моему, естественнее сказать "волк загрыз овцу".

Comment: Теперь понятно, почему волк "зарезал" овцу. Всем спасибо за ответы!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотя какие зубы. Волчьи клыки очень большие и после них след как от ножа. К тому же волки стараются убить свою жертву одним укусом, в то время как под "загрыз" обычно понимаются множественные раны разных частей тела.

Answer (score 1):

Информация из Интернета: волки "режут" одним ударом клыка по сонной артерии.